# Aspx asp.net - How do I best display content dynamically, based on user choice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I am building a site that is going to be used to track people through gps, and show them on a big google maps. And then you're going to be able to contact these people by clicking on their marker and writing them a sms.

The problem i have is that i have a dropdown menu, that resembles an sms inbox, and then when the user click's on a "chat" from the inbox ([sms-inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRZ9z.png)), the inbox should change layout, and show all the messages they have had with this person, and be able to write new messages. (basically it should look like it does on a normal phone).

Finally here is my question: How do i best get the messages from a web service or database without refreshing the entire page? i have tried working with UpdatePanel, but it dose not seem to be the best match.. maybe im wrong.

Sorry for the bad english, and if i have forgotten anything in the post.

[Here is a picture of the full site, just to get a better idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haW9V.gif)

Comment: Also give a look on jQuery, and ASP.Net MVC, SignalR

Comment: I total agree with @Tony using `Jquery` and `SignalR` will have better perspective

Comment: Okay, i will have a look at SignalR, thank's guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare webMethod like this:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetMessages(int id)
    { ... }
```

Then you can access it with AJAX request like this

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CS.aspx/GetMessages",
        data: '{id: "1" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });

function OnSuccess(response)
{

}
```

Comment: Im already using this to update my markers with new gps locations from a web service every 30 seconds. but im not sure how to create new html, (ex. a new div for every message i get back). but im sure i can learn how from a couple of searches on google. Thank you!!